# Как сделать 3 кнопки сразу в низ и по центру?

Tags: html, css

```
<button class="button-settings2 btn-2" >Магазин</button>
<button class="button-settings3 btn-3" >Профиль</button>
<button class="button-settings4 btn-4" >Настройки</button>
```

1. Нужно что бы эти кнопки были  с   низу и по центру
2. Сделать их    активными под разделы! (Что бы переходило на указанный раздел кнопки)

Answer (score 0):

Можешь сделать вот так, если у вас всё находится в одной папке:
(лучше так)

home.html:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /> <!--Подключает css-->
<div class="center">
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick=" window.open('ссылка','_blank')"> Магазин</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick=" window.open('ссылка','_blank')"> Профиль</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick=" window.open('ссылка','_blank')"> Настройки</button>
</div>
```

'_blank' открывает ссылку в новом окне (если вам это нужно)

style.css:

```css
.center {
    margin-top: 500px; /*Отступ сверху*/
    width: 100%; /*Расположение по ширине */
    text-align: center;
    }
```

А можешь вот так:

home.html:

```css
<div class="center">
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick=" window.open('ссылка','_blank')"> Магазин</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick=" window.open('ссылка','_blank')"> Профиль</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick=" window.open('ссылка','_blank')"> Настройки</button>
</div>
<style>
    .center {
        margin-top: 500px; /*Отступ сверху*/
        width: 100%; /*Расположение по ширине */
        text-align: center;
        }
</style>
```